# using namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, using-directives

I have come to understand why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice in c++
but let's consider for example 2 ( hypothetical ) libraries "std" and "sfd" , both of them contain a function "run()".
would the following be okay or is it still a problem :
( if i want to call "run()" from "std" )

```
   using namespace std;  
   using namespace sfd;  
   int main(){
       std::run();
}
```

( if i want to call "run()" from "sfd" )

```
   using namespace std;
   using namespace sfd;
   int main(){
   sfd::run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem because you are using qualified names in the function calls.

A program would be ill-formed if you used the unqualified function name in its call like

```
run();
```

In this case there would be ambiguity.

Comment: but i have never seen someone suggest this solution whenever addressing this problems , what do you think ?

Comment: @KenZa Usually an accent is made on excluding the using directive.

Comment: i don't think i know what that is but it seems to me that the way i mentioned in the question is better , do you agree ?

Comment: @KenZa It is better either not to use the using directive or to use it in a minimal scope.

Comment: why? there is a problem only if we use the same name for different namespaces but who would do that , or if different namespaces contain similar functions , so it seems to me that this saves time and effort

Comment: or wait  you mean the problem is with the using directive not with namespace ?

Comment: @KenZa Because in general there can be name collisions for numerous entities. introduced by a using directive.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of using `using namespace whatever;` is to avoid typing the name of that namespace (like `std` and `sfd`) every time you want to have access to one of its members (for reasons such as saving time and also making the code look a bit cleaner). There is no problem with your solution though. It works.

But again, why would you want to use `using namespace std;` at the top of your source file if you're eventually going to add `std::` to whichever function that needs it?

You can also write `using namespace std;` in a (function, loop, etc) scope so that it doesn't pollute the whole namespace of that particular source file.

Comment: i will only add if the function is common to both of the namespaces i declared otherwise i wouldn't